# Как отправлять обработанное сообщение в телеграм канал?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, бот

Прошу знающих помочь разобраться, как с помощью библиотеки Aiogram реализовать возможность отправки сообщения от пользователя в телеграм канал? А теперь подробнее: пользователь должен обращаться к боту, отвечать на его вопросы, по типу добавьте описание, ваши контактные данные и так далее, по результату бот должен все ответы собрать в одно сообщение и переслать его в телеграм канал. Честно представить пока не могу, как это реализовать. Ясного ответа не нашел. Может не ту библиотеку использую? Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Используйте fsm - собирайте ответы по частям, а потом собирайте в кучу все и отправляйте в канал

Comment: Благодарю! А есть возможность с помощью fsm отправлять итоговый ответ в несколько каналов? Грубо говоря есть тг каналы с разной тематикой, и по итогу опроса сообщение будет отправляться в нужный канал (в начале опроса пользователь сам выбирает тему опроса).

Comment: Как напишите обработку, так и будет. Хоть в 100 каналов рассылайте